# Can someone explain to me what this sql command is doing

Tags: mysql

what does the m. and r . mean? Is it referencing to a table name by its first letter?also other commands like dayname

i have tables called room,employee,meeting, and participants.

```
select dayname(m.date), count(*) from meeting m, room r where m.room_id=r.room_id group by weekday(m.date) order by weekday(m.date);
```

Thanks for taking your time on this to answer me

EMPLOYEE:
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| staff_id  | int(11)  | NO   |PRI  | NULL    |       | 
| seniority | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| lastname  | char(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| firstname | char(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+

MEETING:
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| meeting_id | int(11)  | NO   |PRI  | NULL    |       | 
| room_id    | int(11)  | YES  |MUL  | NULL    |       | 
| name       | tinytext | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| date       | date     | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+

PARTICIPANT:
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| meeting_id | int(11) | YES  |MUL  | NULL    |       | 
| staff_id   | int(11) | YES  |MUL  | NULL    |       | 
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+

ROOM:
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| room_id | int(11)  | NO   |PRI  | NULL    |       | 
| name    | char(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+

Comment: Can you explain what is a commain ?

Answer (score 1):

`m` and `r` are aliases for the table names `meeting` and `room`. In this case, it's syntactically convenient to reference them by these names rather than writing the entire table name out.

`SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE t.my_column_name = 123;`

In the above example, `t` is a convenient way to specify `my_table`. You can then access columns (attributes) by specifying `t.my_column_name`.

See this for a general explanation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)

---

Regarding `dayname`, I'm tempted to say that this is a user-defined SQL function, located elsewhere in the code. As far as I can tell, this is not reserved. I suggest you look through the rest of the SQL you have and see if you can find where it has been defined.

Comment: is it automatically set to m and r or do i have to set the aliases?

Comment: You have to manually set the aliases to whatever values you prefer to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're aliases for the table names. You defined them yourself in the 'from' section:

```
from meeting m, room r
```

Here you are defining `m` as an alias for the `meeting` table and `r` for `room`. This can be particularly useful if you e.g. joined against the room table twice: you can then give the two instances different aliases.

Comment: can i use meeting.room_id instead of m.room_id?

Comment: In MySQL, yes I think so. It won't work in e.g. Oracle, though: once you've defined an alias you can't use the plain table name. If that doesn't work then remove the `m` from `from meeting m` to remove the alias.

Comment: @user3395201 No not if you alias meeting as m... You should stick  with m as its easy to read and faster to write

Comment: What is the difference between doing this and a Join?

Comment: @meda You mean selecting from two tables in the from statement? Nothing: this is the old SQL join syntax. It's effectively a cross-join I think, but adding constraints (with `where`, not `in`) make it a normal join.